# How to increase max_input_vars via SSH

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

friends I am stuck on the Aws instance of WordPress, I am trying to update max_input _vars

I have tried the script below I've opened php.ini updated to 3000 but when I type php -i | grep max_input_vars I always get 1000

I have restarted PHP but still no luck I've tried all the resources the code is below thank you very much

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
sudo -i nano /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
Control +w = search “max_input_vars” enter and change check line start without “;” 
Control + x yes
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart
php -i | grep max_input_vars
But it again says 1000 instead of 3000
```